# Bison parser: making a function which is returning tokens

Tags: c++, c, bison, flex-lexer

in my flex, I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
{VARIABLE}          { 
                        yylval.string_val=strdup(yytext); 
                        return getVarType(yytext); //that is the issue
                    }
```

My question is, what should be the return type of the getVarType function? I would like it to look something like this:

```
X getVarType(const char* v){
     if(case 1...)
       return VAR_INT;
     if(case 2...)
       return VAR_DOUBLE;
    etc....
}
```

What should X be?

Comment: X is a type of VAR_INT, VAR_DOUBLE, etc. enumeration, I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yylex` returns an `int`. Furthermore, the only meaningful way to return token types which will be understood correctly by your bison/yacc parser is to declare the various `VAR_INT`, `VAR_DOUBLE`, etc... as `%token`s in your bison/yacc file (and import the generated header file, but I presume you are already doing that). The generated header file will declare those variables as `int`.

So your `getVarType` function could return any type `T` as long as you can cast an `int` to a `T` and then cast it back to an `int` without losing information, but the simplest thing would be to return an `int`.

---

Doing type analysis (and consequently managing the symbol table) in the lexer produces a dependency between the lexer and the parser which should generally be avoided, unless you achieve some value from it. In this particular case, it's hard to see what value is being produced, but that's really up to you. It's usually easier to do type analysis on the completed AST than to try to do it during the parse.

In any event, the fact that you have a symbol table at all suggests that it is not necessary to `strdup` the variable names; you could look them up in the symbol table and then return a pointer to the symbol table entry. That will save a lot of work trying to keep track of memory allocations. (It still creates a dependency between the lexer and the parser, but it's not as tight a dependency. From the lexer's viewpoint, the symbol table could be read-only and provided as an extra reference/pointer argument to `yylex`.)

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, Bison 3.0 automatically generates such functions for C++.  For instance, if your input file contains something like:

```
%token <::std::string> TEXT;
%token <int> NUMBER;
%token END_OF_FILE 0;
```

it will generate functions that you can call from the scanner this way:

```
return parser::make_NUMBER (stage, loc);
return parser::make_TEXT ("Text all!", loc);
return parser::make_END_OF_FILE (loc);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void *p;
char *s;
void main()
{
void *p=myFun();
if(strcmp(s,"int")==0)
{
 Print("function return int and val: =%d",(*int)*p);
}
//similarly compare for all data types and just type cast to that data types
}

void *myFun()
{
if(case1)
{
 p=address of that data type variable suppose int;
 s="data type";
}

if(case2)
{
 p=&of that data type variable suppose char etc;
 s="data type";
}
return p;
}
```

I think this is only way but there is one problem that if function returns it destroy all local variables so returning the address of local variables are not error but the value returned by function is valid or not we can't say.
void pointer is called generic pointer we can provide any data type address to this pointer but at the time of retrieving the value type casting is compulsory.
Hope so this will some how help full for you
thanks and regards 
asif aftab